# Bitvise SSH + Git + initial directory

Tags: windows, git, ssh, directory

I am using the Bitvise SSH Server on a Windows machine and I want to create different virtual user accounts to contribute git repositories. (Git push will be performed using ssh).

So for example I can use

```
git clone ssh://mydomain.eu/d/gitrepos/username/repository_name
```

in the client's cmd shell which works perfectly but is somewhat not perfect because everyone could access all repositories + browsing is nesessary all the time.

Thatswhy I want to set an initial shell directory, I have overwritten the option "Initial terminal shell directory" with:

```
"D:\Gitrepos\username"
```

in the virtual-account setting in bitvise ssh.

This seems to work at the first glimpse, when I test it using

```
ssh username@mydomain.eu
```

and enter the password Im in terminal location:

```
D:\Gitrepos\username>
```

just as I wanted.

Now the problem:

When I try to use git from the initial directory:

```
git clone ssh://kratos@tibiafun.eu/repository_name
```

because i should be already in the correct subdirectory it tells me:

```
"fatal: 'D:/Programs/Git/repository_name' does not appear to be a git repository"
```

Which is ofcourse wrong! "D:/Programs/Git" is ofcourse the path of my git installation and I have no clue why it is redirecting me there, it is not even the /bin directory where git.exe is located.

I forgot to mention that I am using:

- OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
- Git: msysgit 1.9.2

Anyone got an idea why this is happening and if its possible how to prevent that?

Thanks!...

Comment: @Andy, nop this works without an extension and as the git error reports, this is definetly the wrong home directory, is there a way to change the home directory for git.exe?

Comment: I'm struggling with the very same problem, have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command:

```
git daemon --base-path=D:/Gitrepos --export-all --enable=receive-pack
```

The Unix style directory separator is intentional.

Comment: Thanks but erm, the git binary? I'd say you talk about git.exe but there are no settings as expected. 
How can I set properties in a binary? What config do you mean? Could you explain that a little more detailed? 

It is most likely that it will solve my problem.

Comment: @Steini What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to mention in my post. I am using: Windows Server 2008 R2 and git: 1.9.2.msysgit.0

Comment: Windows Server doesn't allow this option.  However, I did find how to change it through Git.

Comment: The git daemon command did not help either, same base path as before. But thanks for the attempt. =( I tried to set some config settings like git config --global base-path="D:/Gitrepos" but had no effect. =(

Comment: @Steini How did you install Git?  Was is using their pre-built installer?

Comment: Yes, I used the standard msysgit installer